# Flutter hot-reload stops working when phone goes to sleep

Tags: ios, android-studio, flutter, hot-reload

My setup

- Android Studio 3.5
- Flutter 1.9.1_hotfix.2
- iOS 12

After deploying the app to the phone and keeping the app running, hot-reload works with Android Studio until the phone goes to sleep and gets locked automatically, when the hot-reload button in the Android Studio toolbar is suddenly grayed out, and the Run button is back to green.

Is this by design? Do I need to turn off the auto-lock of my phone when working with Flutter?

Comment: You could just set the off-screen time to let phone keep awaken. There is no way to hot-reload when off-screen in my experience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same, its not about your design. And yes you need to turn off auto-lock.